# Is there any way to connect to SQL Server 2000 from SQL Server 2016 Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler, sql-server-native-client

We're verifying legacy system in SQL Server 2000 and confirmed we can connect it from SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (Need to add TCP port though).

Now we'd like to connect SQL Server Profiler 2016 to 2000, since we'd like to capture running query for some critical reports, but it says :

> Native Client 11.0 can't connect to SQL Server before 2000

I'm just wondering we can connect profiler by OLEDB or else, instead of native client.

Is there anyone know any better idea, please let us know about your solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming question in the sense of SO's policies. You should post it on dba.stackexchange.com or similar sites.

Comment: Why not use the tools designed for 2000? You can't expect a tool created 5+ years after a product became **completely** unsupported to support it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Larnu. Since we don't get any connect information and approval to that regacy server by RDP connection so far, only sql server account and password. So, I asked such a sily question.

Comment: Can you install the SQL 2000 version of Profiler and use that? I have no idea where you would get it though.

Comment: No, we don’t have install media (I was also surprised to hear it’s still running !) We need to verify and migrate data before termination of that legacy system. Anyway thanks for your advice @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I fond this torrent.... I suspect it's not longer active though http://www.picktorrent.com/download/29/836995/microsoft_sql_server_2000_standard_edition_(personal_edition).is/

Comment: I really appreciated your kind advice again, @Nick.McDermaid. Let me try it right after we'll make it another urgent issues. Again, thank you so much for all of your considerations.